# Reader read the right words from the wrong day of Chanukah. Must he repeat?

Tags: chanuka, torah-reading, mistakes

Is the Torah reader required to read the correct portion on Chanukah in the following  or similar circumstance?

It is the second day of Chanukah.
The reader correctly reads the Cohen's portion starting with

יח) בַּיּוֹם, הַשֵּׁנִי, הִקְרִיב, נְתַנְאֵל בֶּן-צוּעָר--נְשִׂיא, יִשָּׂשכָר)

When he comes to read the Levi's portion, instead of reading

כא) פַּר אֶחָד בֶּן-בָּקָר, אַיִל אֶחָד כֶּבֶשׂ-אֶחָד בֶּן-שְׁנָתוֹ--לְעֹלָה).

and on to the end of the parsha, he starts reading the equivalent possukim for the next day,

כז) פַּר אֶחָד בֶּן-בָּקָר, אַיִל אֶחָד כֶּבֶשׂ-אֶחָד בֶּן-שְׁנָתוֹ--לְעֹלָה)

and then corrects himself before the end and ends up with the correct nosi.

He has read one or two wrong pessukim, but the words were right. Does he have to repeat by reading the right words or is this a case of טרחה דצבורה - inconvenience to the community and it is not necessary to repeat?

Comment: The last words are different (the name). I'm confused about the case

Comment: Per ^^^. If the words at the end were "right", it implies that he said the name of the leader for the 2nd day by heart while he was looking at the 3rd day. And, no one corrected him, because he is reading the wrong words? It's essentially making a mistake or reading *Divrei Bikhtav b'al peh* - "written words of Torah are being read by heart." If this is not what you mean, please edit your question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for your comment; you're right of course. I simplified the case. He started reading the equivalent possukim for the next day, corrected himself before the end and ended up with the correct nosi. I have edited the question as requested by DanF.

Comment: If you're saying that he ends up with the correct Nossi, i.e. while he is reading the par. for the 3rd day, he says the name for the 2nd day - did I get this right? If so, he is saying words by heart, which, I think is against halacha. Of course, the cong. may not know what's happening, but the reader and the oleh know. If he's using a yad, I'm surprised that the gabba'im aren't paying attention to where he's pointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mishna berura deals with this issue in סימן תרפד סעיף קטן ג at the end. If someone read the nasi for the third day on the second day (or the like) then he is still yotzai (`עלתה להם`) because we are not makpid on the day. `אין קפידה ליום`. The magid shiur added on this that since he is yotzei reading the complete wrong day (even kohen) then just reading the wrong Levi would be OK.

Comment: This is not the OP's case exactly. In the OP's case, the reader jumped in the middle of the aliya from one section to the other.